# OpenGL not displaying indicies correclty for cube?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rendering, object-files

I was teaching myself opengl (in c++) and I thought it through and got a working set of indices that make a cube:

```
GLushort indicies[] =
{
    2, 0, 1,
    1, 2, 3,
    3, 1, 4,
    5, 1, 4,
    4, 5, 7,
    7, 5, 6,
    0, 7, 6,
    0, 7, 2,
    7, 0, 1,
    1, 7, 4,
    6, 5, 3,
    6, 3, 2
};
```

now, I'm trying to load in an obj file from blender of a cube and these are the indicies it's giving me:

```
GLushort indicies[] =
{
    5,3,1,
    3,8,4,
    7,6,8,
    2,8,6,
    1,4,2,
    5,2,6,
    5,7,3,
    3,7,8,
    7,5,6,
    2,4,8,
    1,3,4,
    5,1,2
};
```

From my understanding, it doesn't really matter what order do your indicies in, as long as each set of three make a triangle. However, when I ran what blender's exported obj file gave me, my cube was all messed up. I though maybe the indicies had to be base 0 instead of base one, so I subtracted 1 from each index to make them base 0:

```
GLushort indicies[] =
{
    4,2,0,
    2,7,3,
    6,5,7,
    1,7,5,
    0,3,1,
    4,1,5,
    4,6,2,
    2,6,7,
    6,4,5,
    1,3,7,
    0,2,3,
    4,0,1
};
```

My cube was somewhat better but still had a bottom that looked like this:

[image]

What am I missing? Shouldn't any combination of indicies, no matter how you think of them, work as long as each set of three make a triangle?

Comment: It would be significantly easier if you gave us the vertices position array, too.

Comment: It was the vertices. I had different vertex positions from what blender what setting. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You cube, in Blender export, is like this (or some isomorphism of it)

```
  3----7
 /    /|
0----1 |
|    | 6
|    |/
4----5
```

with 2 hidden behind.

(4,2,0) is half the left side.
(2,7,3) is half the back.
(6,5,7) is half the right side, and so on.

Your vertices, though, don't make sense. Let's say this is the first triangle

```
0----1
|   /
|/
2
```

Then you'll have

```
0----1
|   /|
|/   |
2----3
```

But notice that (2,0,1) are clockwise and (1,2,3) are counter-clockwise. OpenGL, like most 3D system will consider only CW or CCW triangles as front-facing and will not display the backward-facing ones.

That's a first issue to solve. Make sure all triangles are CW or all triangles are CCW.

Comment: I found that it was the vertex positions as they were not matching blender's. However, I thank you for the insight into this potential issue as well.